# Why cant I pass values for dateSentBefore & datesentAfter parameters as a variable in c#?

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I have to code in C# to read all messages sent between datesentAfter & dateSentBefore

```
using System;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;


class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        const string accountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        const string authToken = "XXXXXXXXXX";

        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var messages = MessageResource.Read(
            dateSentBefore: new DateTime(2019, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0),
            dateSentAfter: new DateTime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
            limit: 20
        );

        foreach(var record in messages)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(record.Sid);
        }
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly like this. It lists all the messages.

But when instead of hardcoding the dates, I pass it as a variable, the code runs without error but doesn't return any messages for me.

```
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string accountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        const string authToken = "XXXXXXXXXX";
        int be_yyyy = 2019;
        int be_mm = 5;
        int be_dd = 20;
        int af_yyyy = 2019;
        int af_mm = 5;
        int af_dd = 19;
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var messages = MessageResource.Read(
            dateSentBefore: new DateTime(be_yyyy, be_mm, be_dd, 0, 0, 0),
            dateSentAfter: new DateTime(af_yyyy, af_mm, af_dd, 0, 0, 0),
            limit: 20
        );

        foreach(var record in messages)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(record.Sid);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why cant I do this? or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Based on a quick scan, that code looks ok to me.  Have you put a break point in the `MessageResource.Read` function to confirm the values passed in? I expect you'd find them to me as expected - perhaps an error in that method instead?

Comment: You're passing different dates. Maybe there isn't any data between the 19th and the 20th. Try reproducing the problem with exactly the same arguments as in your first example. (Troubleshooting in general is much easier when you vary only one thing at a time).

Comment: Did you try giving the variables the same test values as the hard-coded values you used in the first code block that returned data?

Answer (score 0):

Really late response so you probably already have an answer but found this question whilst looking for an answer to my own problem.

You're looking for **messages after 19 April 00:00**
AND **messages before 20 April 00:00**

So you're **only** getting data of **the 19th of april**.

As said before, you're using different input from your first example, try using the same input. The first example looks at data from 2 months so there's much more likely to be data in there. And check if there is any data on the 19th to find. Code looks fine.